# Inconveniente con código para crear menús

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Cordial saludo espero se encuentren bien, agradezco por favor su colaboración con el siguiente inconveniente que se me presenta.
Tengo el siguiente código con nombre administrador.php, en el cual en la primera parte del código se accede de acuerdo al rol que un usuario ingrese.
Código enunciado del 1 al 10.
El código enunciado del 11 al 23. representa la visualización de los menús de acuerdo al tipo de rol que ingresa el usuario.

```
1.<?php
2.include_once ('Conexion/database.php');
3 session_start();
4. if(!isset($_SESSION['rol'])){
5.header('location: index.php');
6. }else{
7.       if($_SESSION['rol']!=1){
8.            header('location: index.php');
9.        }   
10.  }

11.if(isset($_GET['idmenu']) && isset($_GET['nombremenu']) && isset($_GET['rol_id'])&& 12.isset($_GET['roles_rol_id'])){
13. $idmenu = $_GET['idmenu'];
14. $nombremenu=  $_GET['nombremenu'];
15. $rol_id = $_GET['rol_id'];
16. $roles_rol_id=  $_GET['roles_rol_id'];
17.$db=new Database();
18.    $query=$db->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM menu WHERE estado=1');
19.    $query->execute(['idmenu'=> $idmenu,'nombremenu'=> $nombremenu,'rol_id'=> 
20.   $result=$mysqli->query($query); 
21.  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
22. }
23. ?>

<html lang="en"> 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Menú Administrador de la aplicación</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">  <!-- Ojo poner a todos los firmularios para que tomen estilos.css-->
<style>
   li{
     width: calc(100%/<?php echo $row;?>);
}
</style>


  </head>      
<body>
   <div id="contenedor">   <!--contenedor es un segmento de código de estilos.css -->
  <header>
  <h1>Administador</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
  <ul>
   <?php
   while($fila=$row) //$row me trae el fetch_array
    {
      echo '<li><a href="#">'. $fila['nombremenu'] . '</a></li>';   

    }
   
   ?>

   </ul>
  </nav>

 </body>
</html>
```

Al ejecutar el error que me sale es el siguiente:

[image: Explicacion de error mostrado]

El error que me sale es: Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp64\www\Grupo4sas\admin.php on line 71

La línea 71, tiene el siguiente código:

```
while($fila=$row)
```

tomé como ejemplo el siguiente código publicado en youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARoQow2UJyQ&t=692s

pero en este video se utilizaron instrucciones como

mysqli_query,
mysqli_num_rows
mysqli_fetch_array.

Funciones que veo que son obsoletas.

Muchas gracias por su colaboración!.

Comment: El problema es que ejecutas la consulta solo si hay ciertos valores en `$_GET`, que es donde defines la variable `$row` y, si no existen los valores, tampoco la variable. Además, solo lees una fila de resultados con `$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);` y el ciclo se va a volver infinito porque `$row` no avanzará el apuntador de resultados de MySQL. Te recomiendo leer el manual y ver el [primer ejemplo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#95881) para saber cómo recorrer los resultados.

Comment: Gracias, puse:   $result=$mysqli->query($query);
Comentarie la siguiente linea de código:
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);  
Modifique el while, haciendo lo siguiente:
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM))
{echo '<li><a href="#">'. $fila['nombremenu'] . '</a></li>'; }?>
Ahora me muestra los siguientes errores:

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\wamp64\www\Grupo4sas\admin.php
Warning: Use of undefined constant MYSQL_NUM - assumed 'MYSQL_NUM' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\wamp64\www\Grupo4sas\admin.php on line 68
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp64\www\Grupo4sas\admin.php on line 68

Answer (score 0):

Las correcciones que mencionas en comentarios van bien encaminadas, solo falta saber qué hacer cuando no hay valores en `$_GET`; revisa los comentarios en el código para ver qué fue lo que se modificó y porqué:

```
<?php
include_once ('Conexion/database.php');
session_start();
// Simplifica con un solo if
if(!isset($_SESSION['rol']) || $_SESSION['rol'] != 1) {
    header('location: index.php');
    // Debes finalizar el script o se seguirá ejecutando
    exit;
}
// Define la variable $result, por si no hay valores en $_GET
$result = false;
if(isset($_GET['idmenu']) && isset($_GET['nombremenu']) && isset($_GET['rol_id'])&& 12.isset($_GET['roles_rol_id'])) {
    $idmenu = $_GET['idmenu'];
    $nombremenu=  $_GET['nombremenu'];
    $rol_id = $_GET['rol_id'];
    $roles_rol_id=  $_GET['roles_rol_id'];
    $db=new Database();
    $query=$db->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM menu WHERE estado=1');
    $query->execute(['idmenu'=> $idmenu,'nombremenu'=> $nombremenu,'rol_id'=> $rol_id]); 
    $result=$mysqli->query($query); 
    // Aquí no lees registros
}
?>

<html lang="en"> 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Menú Administrador de la aplicación</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">  <!-- Ojo poner a todos los firmularios para que tomen estilos.css-->
<style>
   li{
     width: calc(100%/<?php echo $row;?>);
}
</style>
</head>      
<body>
    <div id="contenedor">   <!--contenedor es un segmento de código de estilos.css -->
    <header>
        <h1>Administador</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
<?php
// Ejecutar ciclo solo si $result no es falso
// a) Hay valores en $_GET
// b) La consulta se ejecutó correctamente
// Aunque es probable que no haya resultados
if($result) {
    // Lee los registros con feth_assoc()
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<li><a href="#">'. $row['nombremenu'] . '</a></li>';   

    }
?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Cuando usas `$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)` obtienes un arreglo numérico y, al querer acceder a `$row['nombremenu']`, lo estás haciendo por nombre (arreglo asociativo) y te va a dar error de índice no definido, es por eso que te sugiero [fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby, un cordial saludo no me genera errores, , por el momento ya no me muestra esos errores, el paso que  me toca seguir es ver como hago para visualizar los menús.